# What's a good, multi-platform writing app? (that's not Google docs or Evernote)

Tags: creative-writing, software

Sorry if this question has been asked a lot

I've been writing for a year now and have used both Google docs and Evernote and found them both to be lacking

**Google docs:** I'm a writer who likes to flit between chapters (I have all my chapters in separate documents), so I find it very cumbersome changing between google documents to find the exact chapter from the exact book I want

**Evernote:** I love the way that notebooks are structured in evernote. It's everything I wanted from google docs. Unfortunately, it also has its problems. You can't change text colour on the phone app (which is how I do my edits). You can't add comments. Evernote struggles a lot when I want to copy a large chunk of text (this is what broke the camel's back for me)

I've tried googling, but I can't seem to find anything that fits my needs

I'd like something multi-platform because I write on my phone as well as my PC

Does any such app exist?

Comment: have not tried this in a decade, but just an old-style word document, which you share with e.g. dropbox, worked for me (in which case, editing on the pc is much more comfortable than on the phone, but you can still work on the phone if you have to)

Answer (score 1):

Organon is a plug-in for Libre Office, which is available on both Linux and Windows (there's a Mac fork of OpenOffice or Libre Office, but I'm not sure Organon is available for the Mac version).

The resulting document will be in .odt (Open Document Text) format, and can be opened on Android devices with AndrOpenOffice (again, not sure if there's an iOS version).  There's no Organon for Android, as far as I know, because it depends on plug-in capability that was introduced after the switch from Open to Libre.

Comment: I'm a little confused by Organon. Not really sure how to get it to work

Comment: How do I create a project in it

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how to create a project @zeiss ikon

Comment: I'm not an expert on Organon, just aware that it exists and is a writing project management tool, roughly equivalent to Scrivener, but tied to Libre Office.  I'd have to recommend checking the web for tutorials.

Comment: I tried following an Organon manual but it was no help. So I've decided to just use Scrivener (which meant I had to buy an iphone unfortunately because it isn't on Android)

Comment: @klippy Well, there you are -- definition of a killer app.